# Url to tkinter img converter producing discolored images

Tags: python, image, tkinter

The url to image decoding process that I got from the internet seems to be manipulating images very weirdly and discoloring them, and as I have no idea how the process works I'm not able to figure out what the problem is. if you take this url: https://cdn.w600.comps.canstockphoto.com/human-freedom-happiness-in-nature-stock-photo_csp5610464.jpg and try to open it, it will show you the original image. But if you take the code below and try to convert that into a tkinter compatible image, it produces the same thing except the everything got tinted with blue and her skirt became yellow. Can someone figure out what the issue is or provide a better method of converting images into a format readable by tkinter? Thank you!

```
import cv2
import urllib.request as req
import numpy as np
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
imgUrl='https://cdn.w600.comps.canstockphoto.com/human-freedom-happiness-in-nature-stock-photo_csp5610464.jpg'
image1=''
def url_to_image(url):
    # download the image, convert it to a NumPy array, and then read
    # it into OpenCV format
    resp = req.urlopen(url)
    image = np.asarray(bytearray(resp.read()), dtype="uint8")
    image = cv2.imdecode(image, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    # return the image
    return image

class ImageFrame:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("Image")
        #root.geometry("1920x1080")
        master.config(bg="black")
        master.resizable(False,False)
        self.image=Label(master, image=imgma1)
        self.image.pack()
root = Tk()
imgmal = Image.fromarray(url_to_image(imgUrl))
imgmal.thumbnail((600, 650))
imgma1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imgmal)
mainWindow = ImageFrame(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

The image color mode of `OpenCV` is in `BGR`, so you need to convert to `RGB` using `cv2.cvtColor()`:

```py
...
image = cv2.imdecode(image, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) # convert BGR to RGB
...
```